# Adding different versions of same plugin in Feature file

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

While trying to generate build we get some plugin dependencies. When trying to add them in .product file, It shows plugin version as 0.0.0 by default. We have a situation to add more than one version of same plugins.

We tried to manually change 0.0.0 to the required version from the dependencies. We are successfully able to launch the application. But while trying to generate a build we get some errors.We have the required plugins installed.

If anyone knows how to add different versions, the help is much appreciated.

Edit:

[Image showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnEPV.png)
This is the problem we are facing

[The solution we tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqlQC.png)
We tried manually changing version number but creates error during build generation

Comment: Note that if the Bundle-SymbolicName in the MANIFEST.MF has `singleton:=true` then only one of the plug-ins will ever be loaded

Comment: Thanks greg. But my problem is not adding in the manifest. We have to add in the product file.

Comment: I realise that, what I am warning you about is that if the plug-ins have singleton:=true you can't have two versions of the plug-in.

Comment: Hi Greg. I checked and the plugins doesn't have singleton true. I have added two images to the post for further clarification

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this scenario is supported by PDE Build, because it sounds exotic a bit.

You can try to use different features to introduce different version of bundle.

But I think that more promissing strategy will be to "align" your dependencies, i.e. in your case it is better to select the version of GMF that uses the right Batik version.
Otherwise sooner or later you will get "blocking" bundle with `singleton:true` in your dependency tree, as @greg-449 mentioned.

Also, please have a look at this question: [Tycho | How to build multiple version of same plugin using tycho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329069/tycho-how-to-build-multiple-version-of-same-plugin-using-tycho?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

See my answer there:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62426443/9062163

In fact the details I mentioned in my other answer where the result of a successful integration of Sirius 6.0.1 in an Eclipse RCP based on Photon. The troubles came from the integration of Batik 1.7 and 1.6 in the same product, the latter version being forced by the GMF version I use. I also needed some batik plugins of versions 1.8.0 and 1.9.1 for other reasons.